# Dependencies between projects in module

Tags: maven, build, dependency-management

Let's say you have 4 projects depending on each other in chain:
A depends on B, B depends on C, C depends on D.
All projects are built using maven.

What's the best practice for keeping their versions in sync so that when someone updates project D or C it doesn't break the build of project A?

Comment: You should create a multi module build out of it ...

Comment: You need to provide more information on A, B, C and D. Are these independent? Do different teams develop them? Are they released together or follow a different release cycle? Are they simple modules or more complex on their own? There is no generic answer to a question that is this broad.

Comment: @wemu A, B, C and D are mostly developed by one team, but sometimes another team changes C and (the lowest level projects). C and D are more or less simple and they are intended to be libraries (APIs) used by A and B and projects from other teams. A and B are quite complex and produce multiple services each.

Comment: @khmarbaise the problem with this approach is that C and D are used and modified by another team as well.

Comment: sound like using snapshot versions and dependencies during development is the most easy way. I then would set up the CI server to release the projects with their real version and use the versions plugin to set that version on the dependencies down the dependency tree. So any errors are detected and if things work you have a set of versions you know works. Create these releases as you need new deployed versions (daily, wekely, ... - or per commit).

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind Maven was to include modularity in different projects. This makes teams working on these projects independent and they can work on their respective modules without worrying about other teams.

But we may run into situations where a new version of dependent project has been published and we are not aware of it. If you are running Maven 2 to resolve this issue, you can use `<version>LATEST</version>` command in the pom.xml for that particular dependency. So it would be like -

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
 </dependency>
```

But this was discontinued from Maven 3. As per official note from Maven -

> Plugin Metaversion Resolution Internally, Maven 2.x used the special
>   version markers RELEASE and LATEST to support automatic plugin version
>   resolution. These metaversions were also recognized in the 
>   element for a  declaration. For the sake of reproducible
>   builds, Maven 3.x no longer supports usage of these metaversions in
>   the POM. As a result, users will need to replace occurrences of these
>   metaversions with a concrete version.

So it is advisable to always use concrete versions.

However, if you still want the latest versions of dependencies to be used, you can use below command in Maven command prompt -

> mvn versions:use-latest-versions